# Validate c++ sorted lines with 'uniq'

Tags: c++, sorting, unix, command-line, uniq

I have implemented an external sorting algorithm and would like to validate its output.

I have used `std::less` and  `string_a < string_b` for sorting (they are identical, right?).

Now I would like to validate my output using e.g. unix's `sort -c`.

Yet `sort` seems to use a different sorting schema than c++. Is there a way to make it operate the same way as `std::less`/ `string::operator<` ?

Comment: You are aware that the `uniq` and `sort` commands do different things? One removes adjacent duplicate lines, and the other sort lines.

Comment: oh yes, you are right. `sort -c` is what I need. Thx

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing how your output lines are formed

Comment: If you really want to guarantee that the output always matches `sort`'s rules, then you should just call `sort`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did is most mundane, yet solves my issue.
I wrote another c++ program which iterates over each line of the output file and asserts: `current_line <= next_line`.